# How set your own stringFormat in DatePipe 'short' in angular 7?

Tags: angular, localization

I,m set LOCALE_ID in my application, and it solve a lot problem with translation and localization, but one thing I can't solve yet.
It's DatePipe's pre-defined format options, 
eg: 'short': equivalent to 'M/d/yy, h:mm a' (6/15/15, 9:03 AM).

How I can change it to M/d/yy h:mm (without comma between date and time)

This comma apear in date time picker control and anoyed me
[image]

I would like to change only this format option.
'M/d/yy, h:mm a' => 'M/d/yy h:mm a'

Answer (score 2):

You need to use DatePipe for your `div` or another table tag with the parameters `date:"M/d/yy h:mm a"`.

`<div>{{yourDate | date:"M/d/yy h:mm a"}}</div>`

Comment: I use datetime picker
             <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Date and time</mat-label>
                <input matInput [owlDateTime]="timeFrom" [(ngModel)]="applyUpdateDateTimeUtc">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="timeFrom"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <owl-date-time #timeFrom></owl-date-time>
            </mat-form-field>